# Attack2 bind question in CS GO

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm trying to use the next bind:

```
bind "h" "+attack2;-attack2;+attack;-attack"
```

it's supposed to be the same as pressing right mouse button and then the left one... but it just does nothing. Why?

I tried all variations already with no luck. I also tested both, autoexec (config_default actually) and a separate cfg file :( please advise.

I also noticed this line in the config_default:

```
bind "MOUSE1" "+attack"
```

so.... there is no need to use "-attack" or what?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is not need to do `-attack` or `-attack2` it is automatically called by Source.

You'd probably want just `bind "h" "+attack;+attack2"`

After binding you can do `host_writeconfig` to save your binds, place it in the `autoexec.cfg` or other CFG files in the directory.

Comment: well, actually using your command, I got the `attack2` action looped :) and it stops when I use `-attack2`

Comment: Huh, interesting... I'll test later today I normally play Garry's Mod and I'm pretty sure the binds there work like that.

Comment: This is what I also tested today: 

`alias +shooter "+attack"
alias -shooter "-attack"

alias +scopes "+attack2"
alias -scopes "-attack2"

bind "h" "+shooter;+scopes"`

it just loops the "+attack2" until I manually use "-attack2".

Why it's like that (because +attack doesn't get looped) and how to fix it?

Comment: Wait to clarify what are you trying to do? Zoom in, and shoot when pressing `H` then when releasing zoom out and stop shooting?
.
Or are you trying to Zoom in and shoot and stay there while you continue to shoot unill `H` is released?

Comment: the first option.... basically a fast scope and shoot :) but the second option is also fine, I'm just trying to understand why it doesn't work in any way

Comment: Is mine not working? I have it doing `+attack2` to zoom and `+attack` to shoot and it fired when I tested it and zoomed then ended after I released it.

Comment: you mean `bind "h" "+attack;+attack2"` ? for me, it doesn't :(

Comment: `alias "+shooter" "+attack;+attack2"` and `alias "-shooter" "-attack;-attack2"` then `bind "h" "+shooter"` seemed to work it was the only one I tried.

Comment: I just tried and it just shoots but doesn't scope after shooting

Answer (score 1):

First off, no - you don't need to bind -attack. When you release the key or button the game knows where to stop. In aliases you need to tell the game where to stop by creating a -alias and this can then be used to create custom stuff.

*Theoretically* your plan would work using an alias, but it doesn't.

```
alias +snipe "+attack2; +attack"
alias -snipe "-attack; -attack2"
bind mouse1 +snipe
```

Although this bind would or should work it doesn't work (probably forbidden by the devs).

You can try it out using something else. For example this one:

```
alias +snipe "+jump; +attack"
alias -snipe "-attack; -jump"
bind mouse1 +snipe
```

This actually works. Using this alias you jump when you shoot and stop jumping when you release the mouse button.

Fun fact: aliases can be used to bypass -attack and others, like using mouse1 to keep firing:

```
alias spray "+attack"
alias nospray "-attack"
bind mouse1 spray
bind mouse2 nospray
```